# how to write java client and server applications that uses mutual ssl authentication between them?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jsse

I'm building two java applications which have to communicate using SSL two way authentication, I used instructions [from here](http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-create-clientserver-keystores.html)  to create client and server certificates.
then I built a webService in the server application like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testssl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String testSSl(@RequestBody String name) {       
    return = successfully tested;
}
```

and I edited tomcat `server.xml` file to enable SSL like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="keyStore/server.jks"
           keystorePass="server123" />
```

and put server.jks in Tomcat/Jenkins-Tomcat/keystore/server.jks
then I built the client application to invoke this web service through SSL using spring RestTemplate like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\test\\server.jks");
props.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
props.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "server123");

props.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\test\\client.jks");
props.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
props.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "client123");

props.put("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
props.put("ws.ssl.loose.disableHostnameVerification", "true");

System.setProperties(props);
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.createDefault();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
    new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory cc = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate(cc);
String resp = rest.postForObject("https://10.141.0.77:8443/Monim/testssl", "monim", String.class);
System.err.println(resp);
```

but when I run this application I get `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` exception. I tried to create the certificates again but the error still present.
when I request the url from firefox browser I get `An error occurred during a connection to 10.141.0.77:8443. SSL peer cannot verify your certificate. (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_alert)`
and when using chrome to access the url I get

```
Error code: ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
```

here is the stacktrace of the client application

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://10.141.0.77:8443/Monim/testssl":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:503)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:302)
at com.ebs.csh.sva.handler.SOAPMessage.SendingSoapPostMsg(SOAPMessage.java:135)
at com.ebs.csh.sva.handler.SVAHandler.creditSVA(SVAHandler.java:136)
at com.ebs.csh.sva.services.SVAService.creditSVA(SVAService.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.ebs.commons.services.CommonService.processRequest(CommonService.java:276)
at com.ebs.csh.commons.services.CSHService.processRequest(CSHService.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy16.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.ebs.commons.webServices.CommonWebService.processRequest(CommonWebService.java:80)
at com.ebs.csh.commons.webServices.CSHWebService.processRequest(CSHWebService.java:63)
at com.ebs.csh.sva.webServices.SVAWebService.creditSVA(SVAWebService.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1836)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1337)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:966)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:357)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:88)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
... 60 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319)
... 82 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 88 more
```

how to fix this error.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after spending a long time to make this work, the solution is as follows:
first when setting the properties using `System.put("key", "value")` I noticed after many tries it is not setting the `KeyStore` value *it is does not appear in the ssl log* , also tried to set the properties as parameters in the tomcat configuration using `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=""` this also didn't work.
so I read the `KeyStore` from an `InputStream` like this:

```
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream io = new FileInputStream("path/to/jks/file.jks");
    try{
        keystore.load(io, "pass".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        io.close();
    }
```

and use the same previous code to read the `TrustStore` like :

```
    KeyStore trustStore= KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("path/to/truststore/file.jks");
    try{
        keystore.load(stream, "trusted".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
```

after that define the `SSLContext` :

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, "keyPassword".toCharArray())
            .loadTrustMaterial(truststore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
```

`loadKeyMaterial` used to load the `keyStore` it takes the password of your privateKey `"keyPassword"` as a parameter, so you must protect the private key using a password, when I tried to use a plain private key not encrypted "protected" with a password, I get exception which says: `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`, by default this is the same as the keystore password unless you changed it.
then create the `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` and pass it as a parameter to the `HttpClient` ..
this worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to implement 2 way mutual auth, following code worked perfectly for me.

```
    FileInputStream keystoreInputStream = null;
    FileInputStream truststoreInputStream = null;
    try {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystoreInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Aman\\STSProj\\AppSecurity\\clientkeystore.p12");
        keystore.load(keystoreInputStream, "client".toCharArray());

        keystoreInputStream.close();

        KeyStore trustore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        truststoreInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Aman\\STSProj\\AppSecurity\\clienttruststore.p12");
        trustore.load(truststoreInputStream, "client".toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().useProtocol("TLS")
                .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, "client".toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustore, null).build();

        HostnameVerifier hostnameverifier = null;

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
                null, null, hostnameverifier);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemp = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        String greetings = restTemp
                .getForObject("https://localhost:8443/SecureAppServer/test/security/hello/aman123", String.class);

        System.out.println("Received greetings from secured server ---> " + greetings);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        if (keystoreInputStream != null) {
            try {
                keystoreInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (truststoreInputStream != null) {
            try {
                truststoreInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```